# How to achieve xlink:title in react

Tags: reactjs, svg

everyone. I hope everyone is doing great and are healthy.

Recently, I started working with svg images in react and stuck with one thing. I know how to do that thing in html however, not sure how I can do in react.

What I'm trying to achieve is if I hover over a state then it's name should be visible.

If I code in html :

```
<a xlink:title="Andaman Nicobar"> //using xlink:title I can show the name.
 <path
    id='IN-AN'
    title='Andaman and Nicobar Islands'
    d='m 537.188,685.44148 -0.041,0.4695 0.768,0.30627 0.104,2.47542 1.258,1.84675 -0.71,-0.0232 0.661,0.93295 -0.574,0.18739 -0.437,0.94503 0.103,1.88201 -0.409,0.42617 -0.663,-0.49065 -0.502,1.30269 -0.461,-0.2156 0.224,-1.08911 -0.606,-0.31434 -0.121,-1.2503 -0.813,-0.73346 0.069,-0.77879 -1.076,-1.12336 -0.646,0.17933 -0.121,-1.96159 0.365,-0.27304 -0.4,-0.27001 0.64,-1.36616 0.994,0.0584 0.564,-0.57427 0.878,0.27505 0.092,-0.68006 0.86,-0.14307 z m -2.826,-4.29496 0.895,1.77017 -2.249,2.47845 -0.57,-1.39035 0.238,-1.31478 1.704,-0.4695 -0.018,-1.07399 z m -6.972,-12.28743 0.62,0.37378 0.054,0.95511 0.372,-0.12392 0.733,0.79995 -0.07,1.22108 -0.819,-0.73849 -1.384,0.38789 -0.288,-0.63372 0.323,-0.48259 -0.855,0.17027 0.198,-1.45785 1.116,-0.47151 z m 3.502,-0.0695 0.743,0.76973 -0.11,1.34098 -1.472,-1.19389 0.529,-0.85234 0.383,0.60853 -0.073,-0.67301 z m 0.656,-2.05731 0.291,1.85178 -0.652,-1.69864 0.361,-0.15314 z m -1.091,-2.2447 0.394,0.70928 -0.884,1.04981 0.947,1.26743 0.041,1.10422 -0.412,-0.27001 -0.465,0.31837 -0.158,0.77476 -0.325,-0.99943 0.426,0.0796 0.114,-0.58536 0.146,0.45237 0.247,-0.67099 -0.938,0.56621 0.092,-0.83824 -0.627,-0.64883 -0.116,-1.08809 1.518,-1.22109 z m -6.096,-0.7264 0.087,0.94704 -0.404,-0.51281 0.317,-0.43423 z m -2.282,-1.91123 0.359,0.19848 -0.356,1.48404 1.639,1.28758 -0.11,0.45942 -1.593,-0.57024 -0.756,-1.02865 0.157,-1.47599 0.66,-0.35464 z m -1.725,-2.48851 0.285,0.72439 -0.466,-0.2005 0.181,-0.52389 z m 11.976,-2.12381 0.554,2.22556 -0.33,0.0282 -0.08,0.96619 -0.144,-3.21996 z m -17.337,-14.22082 0.765,1.02563 0.632,-0.27504 -0.606,0.35464 0.105,1.13444 -0.86,0.46244 -1.209,-0.15818 -0.228,-1.89409 0.96,-0.0353 0.151,-0.86645 0.29,0.25187 z m -5.693,-35.18985 0.303,0.69114 0.034,-0.42113 0.553,0.46244 0.043,1.32486 0.571,0.30426 0.19,2.31624 -1.188,1.3984 0.616,0.72339 -1.181,1.43165 -1.64,-0.7798 -1.035,0.34255 0.738,-1.75809 -0.843,-1.12537 -0.088,-2.43411 0.448,0.45035 1.244,-2.15202 0.892,-0.62565 0.231,0.45942 0.112,-0.60853 z m 2.629,-13.08436 0.929,1.5727 -0.763,0.62868 0.924,0.42415 -0.055,0.36472 -1.862,0.51684 -0.434,-0.43927 0.123,-0.72237 0.751,-0.10478 -0.195,-1.47195 0.582,-0.76872 z m -0.926,-0.67402 -0.284,0.15415 0.186,-0.91783 0.098,0.76368 z m -7.918,-1.08407 1.085,0.17632 -0.019,1.31679 -1.158,-0.1481 0.092,-1.34501 z m 6.716,-0.23474 0.622,0.3093 -0.822,0.74252 0.2,-1.05182 z m 10.071,-5.13723 1.075,0.16624 -0.465,0.49972 -0.716,-0.34457 0.106,-0.32139 z m -1.074,-4.07532 0.271,-0.21158 0.564,0.52793 0.933,2.47844 -0.237,0.44733 -0.886,-1.45482 -0.543,0.0383 -1.023,-1.01455 0.826,-1.1556 0.095,0.34457 z m 0.412,-1.48405 0.074,1.27046 -0.647,-0.61256 -0.046,-0.72641 0.619,0.0685 z m 0.807,-1.15963 0.371,2.3918 -0.807,-0.65185 0.006,-0.67401 -1.081,-0.74958 0.615,-0.12695 0.421,0.57831 0.475,-0.76772 z m 0.855,-1.16466 0.553,1.47598 -0.427,1.26038 -0.784,-1.06593 0.658,-1.67043 z m -7.699,-0.52088 0.06,1.5052 0.968,-0.15717 -0.584,2.06436 1.288,0.63271 -0.452,0.56521 -0.476,-0.43625 -0.055,0.53498 0.673,0.36169 -1.042,0.80298 0.111,2.37769 0.468,-1.74801 0.792,-0.0836 0.084,0.74555 -0.687,4.25768 -0.257,-0.22467 -0.058,0.48561 -0.813,-0.3637 0.133,0.79189 -0.88,0.34759 0.156,0.61356 0.294,-0.32945 0.144,0.38285 0.739,-0.78081 -0.176,-0.57931 0.734,0.44632 -0.947,4.02394 -0.272,-0.63674 -1.076,-0.31937 0.008,-1.07601 -0.615,0.20452 -0.202,-1.21806 0.583,0.0897 0.174,-0.4433 -0.264,-0.31233 -0.496,0.35061 -0.418,-1.78427 -0.55,0.50173 -0.324,-3.01141 -0.489,0.20553 -0.198,-0.48058 1.023,-2.1097 0.51,1.2624 0.312,-0.20553 0.053,0.83421 0.144,-0.28009 0.264,-4.95991 1.616,-2.84819 z m 0.75,0.37277 0.37,-0.0131 -0.121,0.73346 -0.526,-0.0897 0.277,-0.6307 z m 3.455,-0.807 0.246,0.70021 -0.456,-0.22971 -0.099,0.44733 -0.164,-0.60853 0.473,-0.3093 z m 3.685,-0.13097 0.187,0.52994 0.404,-0.49267 -0.109,1.20698 -0.783,-0.54102 0.301,-0.70323 z m -2.854,-0.40401 -0.404,1.06996 -0.432,-1.22915 0.529,0.16423 0.161,-0.64379 0.146,0.63875 z m -3.45,-0.63271 1.278,0.37076 0.601,-0.27102 0.48,0.85134 -0.638,0.43221 0.453,1.08709 -0.71,-0.0554 0.088,0.85738 -0.591,-0.16523 -0.426,0.74152 0.215,0.5108 -1.001,0.93596 -0.534,-0.67401 0.644,-3.04566 -0.578,-0.18639 0.169,-0.60651 0.297,0.21459 0.359,-0.45639 -0.106,-0.54103 z m 22.254,-0.22568 0.744,0.70223 0.114,1.10321 -1.131,-0.17632 -0.248,-0.86644 0.521,-0.76268 z m -18.511,-2.01398 -0.482,1.18481 -0.272,-0.10982 0.235,-1.08406 0.519,0.009 z m -5.117,-8.89721 0.142,2.36661 -0.486,-1.68957 0.344,-0.67704 z m 3.934,-1.86588 0.482,0.0766 -0.353,0.58737 0.48,0.0252 0.547,1.64928 -0.418,0.71431 0.97,1.37624 -0.47,1.44375 0.217,3.1313 -0.76,0.34254 -0.021,0.31938 0.562,-0.0403 -0.893,0.51483 -0.017,0.81204 -1.764,-0.46949 1.351,2.31019 -1.306,0.3758 -1.274,-0.36774 -0.351,0.51584 -0.719,-0.0997 -0.439,-0.60551 0.168,-5.76087 -0.481,-0.23978 0.412,0.0141 1.029,-1.36013 -0.528,-0.48057 0.377,-0.63069 -0.465,-2.24672 0.291,0.36068 1.548,-1.94044 0.653,0.52189 0,0 0.628,-0.14911 0,0 0.544,-0.70021 z m -4.254,-1.63618 0.507,0.29217 0.034,1.9344 -0.425,1.01455 -0.541,0.11385 0.285,0.41105 -0.437,0.73447 -0.419,-1.68957 0.448,-2.16209 0.548,-0.64883 z m 6.511,-0.1078 -0.569,0.64379 0.07,0.69819 -0.646,-0.12996 0.163,-1.03974 0.261,0.42416 0.721,-0.59644 z m 0.475,-12.41236 0.326,1.0357 -0.216,1.94044 0.222,0.67603 0.337,-0.37076 0.198,0.32341 -0.326,0.51483 0.739,0.99642 -0.519,0.70726 -0.691,-0.90876 -0.617,-0.1743 -0.355,0.52692 -0.337,-0.67502 -0.412,0.35161 1.233,0.51483 0.063,0.93395 0.704,-0.11384 -0.007,0.49065 0.437,-0.28714 -0.721,2.016 0.056,2.10668 -0.648,1.12739 -0.797,-0.13904 0.185,0.47655 -0.837,-1.03369 -0.385,0.14709 -0.306,0.69517 0.771,1.08609 -0.548,0.53195 -0.113,-0.82715 -0.517,0.0494 -0.583,1.18884 0.388,0.95007 0,0 -0.628,0.14911 0,0 -1.021,-0.81909 -10e-4,-1.5314 0.505,-0.0242 0.143,-0.55815 -0.769,-0.1209 0.174,-1.53039 0.535,-0.14911 -0.256,-0.65689 0.785,-0.26396 -0.791,-0.29923 0.378,-1.79838 0.559,-0.44229 -0.669,-0.43121 0.413,-0.53196 -0.431,-0.16825 0.372,-1.40042 0.576,-0.23172 -0.5,-0.35867 0.518,0 0.343,-0.59241 -0.262,-0.89869 1.21,-0.65286 -0.25,-0.74756 0.989,-0.1743 0.506,0.35867 -0.023,-0.97626 0.467,0.67099 0.404,-0.67804 z m -0.285,-2.21549 0.251,1.06089 -1.069,-0.6055 0.818,-0.45539 z m 13.096,-26.52437 -0.617,1.4518 0.021,-0.82615 0.596,-0.62565 z'
/> 
</a>
```

Now, I'm not sure how can I do this in react.

This is what I tried in react:

```
<path
    id='IN-AN'
    title='Andaman and Nicobar Islands'
    d='m 537.188,685.44148 -0.041,0.4695 0.768,0.30627 0.104,2.47542 1.258,1.84675 -0.71,-0.0232 0.661,0.93295 -0.574,0.18739 -0.437,0.94503 0.103,1.88201 -0.409,0.42617 -0.663,-0.49065 -0.502,1.30269 -0.461,-0.2156 0.224,-1.08911 -0.606,-0.31434 -0.121,-1.2503 -0.813,-0.73346 0.069,-0.77879 -1.076,-1.12336 -0.646,0.17933 -0.121,-1.96159 0.365,-0.27304 -0.4,-0.27001 0.64,-1.36616 0.994,0.0584 0.564,-0.57427 0.878,0.27505 0.092,-0.68006 0.86,-0.14307 z m -2.826,-4.29496 0.895,1.77017 -2.249,2.47845 -0.57,-1.39035 0.238,-1.31478 1.704,-0.4695 -0.018,-1.07399 z m -6.972,-12.28743 0.62,0.37378 0.054,0.95511 0.372,-0.12392 0.733,0.79995 -0.07,1.22108 -0.819,-0.73849 -1.384,0.38789 -0.288,-0.63372 0.323,-0.48259 -0.855,0.17027 0.198,-1.45785 1.116,-0.47151 z m 3.502,-0.0695 0.743,0.76973 -0.11,1.34098 -1.472,-1.19389 0.529,-0.85234 0.383,0.60853 -0.073,-0.67301 z m 0.656,-2.05731 0.291,1.85178 -0.652,-1.69864 0.361,-0.15314 z m -1.091,-2.2447 0.394,0.70928 -0.884,1.04981 0.947,1.26743 0.041,1.10422 -0.412,-0.27001 -0.465,0.31837 -0.158,0.77476 -0.325,-0.99943 0.426,0.0796 0.114,-0.58536 0.146,0.45237 0.247,-0.67099 -0.938,0.56621 0.092,-0.83824 -0.627,-0.64883 -0.116,-1.08809 1.518,-1.22109 z m -6.096,-0.7264 0.087,0.94704 -0.404,-0.51281 0.317,-0.43423 z m -2.282,-1.91123 0.359,0.19848 -0.356,1.48404 1.639,1.28758 -0.11,0.45942 -1.593,-0.57024 -0.756,-1.02865 0.157,-1.47599 0.66,-0.35464 z m -1.725,-2.48851 0.285,0.72439 -0.466,-0.2005 0.181,-0.52389 z m 11.976,-2.12381 0.554,2.22556 -0.33,0.0282 -0.08,0.96619 -0.144,-3.21996 z m -17.337,-14.22082 0.765,1.02563 0.632,-0.27504 -0.606,0.35464 0.105,1.13444 -0.86,0.46244 -1.209,-0.15818 -0.228,-1.89409 0.96,-0.0353 0.151,-0.86645 0.29,0.25187 z m -5.693,-35.18985 0.303,0.69114 0.034,-0.42113 0.553,0.46244 0.043,1.32486 0.571,0.30426 0.19,2.31624 -1.188,1.3984 0.616,0.72339 -1.181,1.43165 -1.64,-0.7798 -1.035,0.34255 0.738,-1.75809 -0.843,-1.12537 -0.088,-2.43411 0.448,0.45035 1.244,-2.15202 0.892,-0.62565 0.231,0.45942 0.112,-0.60853 z m 2.629,-13.08436 0.929,1.5727 -0.763,0.62868 0.924,0.42415 -0.055,0.36472 -1.862,0.51684 -0.434,-0.43927 0.123,-0.72237 0.751,-0.10478 -0.195,-1.47195 0.582,-0.76872 z m -0.926,-0.67402 -0.284,0.15415 0.186,-0.91783 0.098,0.76368 z m -7.918,-1.08407 1.085,0.17632 -0.019,1.31679 -1.158,-0.1481 0.092,-1.34501 z m 6.716,-0.23474 0.622,0.3093 -0.822,0.74252 0.2,-1.05182 z m 10.071,-5.13723 1.075,0.16624 -0.465,0.49972 -0.716,-0.34457 0.106,-0.32139 z m -1.074,-4.07532 0.271,-0.21158 0.564,0.52793 0.933,2.47844 -0.237,0.44733 -0.886,-1.45482 -0.543,0.0383 -1.023,-1.01455 0.826,-1.1556 0.095,0.34457 z m 0.412,-1.48405 0.074,1.27046 -0.647,-0.61256 -0.046,-0.72641 0.619,0.0685 z m 0.807,-1.15963 0.371,2.3918 -0.807,-0.65185 0.006,-0.67401 -1.081,-0.74958 0.615,-0.12695 0.421,0.57831 0.475,-0.76772 z m 0.855,-1.16466 0.553,1.47598 -0.427,1.26038 -0.784,-1.06593 0.658,-1.67043 z m -7.699,-0.52088 0.06,1.5052 0.968,-0.15717 -0.584,2.06436 1.288,0.63271 -0.452,0.56521 -0.476,-0.43625 -0.055,0.53498 0.673,0.36169 -1.042,0.80298 0.111,2.37769 0.468,-1.74801 0.792,-0.0836 0.084,0.74555 -0.687,4.25768 -0.257,-0.22467 -0.058,0.48561 -0.813,-0.3637 0.133,0.79189 -0.88,0.34759 0.156,0.61356 0.294,-0.32945 0.144,0.38285 0.739,-0.78081 -0.176,-0.57931 0.734,0.44632 -0.947,4.02394 -0.272,-0.63674 -1.076,-0.31937 0.008,-1.07601 -0.615,0.20452 -0.202,-1.21806 0.583,0.0897 0.174,-0.4433 -0.264,-0.31233 -0.496,0.35061 -0.418,-1.78427 -0.55,0.50173 -0.324,-3.01141 -0.489,0.20553 -0.198,-0.48058 1.023,-2.1097 0.51,1.2624 0.312,-0.20553 0.053,0.83421 0.144,-0.28009 0.264,-4.95991 1.616,-2.84819 z m 0.75,0.37277 0.37,-0.0131 -0.121,0.73346 -0.526,-0.0897 0.277,-0.6307 z m 3.455,-0.807 0.246,0.70021 -0.456,-0.22971 -0.099,0.44733 -0.164,-0.60853 0.473,-0.3093 z m 3.685,-0.13097 0.187,0.52994 0.404,-0.49267 -0.109,1.20698 -0.783,-0.54102 0.301,-0.70323 z m -2.854,-0.40401 -0.404,1.06996 -0.432,-1.22915 0.529,0.16423 0.161,-0.64379 0.146,0.63875 z m -3.45,-0.63271 1.278,0.37076 0.601,-0.27102 0.48,0.85134 -0.638,0.43221 0.453,1.08709 -0.71,-0.0554 0.088,0.85738 -0.591,-0.16523 -0.426,0.74152 0.215,0.5108 -1.001,0.93596 -0.534,-0.67401 0.644,-3.04566 -0.578,-0.18639 0.169,-0.60651 0.297,0.21459 0.359,-0.45639 -0.106,-0.54103 z m 22.254,-0.22568 0.744,0.70223 0.114,1.10321 -1.131,-0.17632 -0.248,-0.86644 0.521,-0.76268 z m -18.511,-2.01398 -0.482,1.18481 -0.272,-0.10982 0.235,-1.08406 0.519,0.009 z m -5.117,-8.89721 0.142,2.36661 -0.486,-1.68957 0.344,-0.67704 z m 3.934,-1.86588 0.482,0.0766 -0.353,0.58737 0.48,0.0252 0.547,1.64928 -0.418,0.71431 0.97,1.37624 -0.47,1.44375 0.217,3.1313 -0.76,0.34254 -0.021,0.31938 0.562,-0.0403 -0.893,0.51483 -0.017,0.81204 -1.764,-0.46949 1.351,2.31019 -1.306,0.3758 -1.274,-0.36774 -0.351,0.51584 -0.719,-0.0997 -0.439,-0.60551 0.168,-5.76087 -0.481,-0.23978 0.412,0.0141 1.029,-1.36013 -0.528,-0.48057 0.377,-0.63069 -0.465,-2.24672 0.291,0.36068 1.548,-1.94044 0.653,0.52189 0,0 0.628,-0.14911 0,0 0.544,-0.70021 z m -4.254,-1.63618 0.507,0.29217 0.034,1.9344 -0.425,1.01455 -0.541,0.11385 0.285,0.41105 -0.437,0.73447 -0.419,-1.68957 0.448,-2.16209 0.548,-0.64883 z m 6.511,-0.1078 -0.569,0.64379 0.07,0.69819 -0.646,-0.12996 0.163,-1.03974 0.261,0.42416 0.721,-0.59644 z m 0.475,-12.41236 0.326,1.0357 -0.216,1.94044 0.222,0.67603 0.337,-0.37076 0.198,0.32341 -0.326,0.51483 0.739,0.99642 -0.519,0.70726 -0.691,-0.90876 -0.617,-0.1743 -0.355,0.52692 -0.337,-0.67502 -0.412,0.35161 1.233,0.51483 0.063,0.93395 0.704,-0.11384 -0.007,0.49065 0.437,-0.28714 -0.721,2.016 0.056,2.10668 -0.648,1.12739 -0.797,-0.13904 0.185,0.47655 -0.837,-1.03369 -0.385,0.14709 -0.306,0.69517 0.771,1.08609 -0.548,0.53195 -0.113,-0.82715 -0.517,0.0494 -0.583,1.18884 0.388,0.95007 0,0 -0.628,0.14911 0,0 -1.021,-0.81909 -10e-4,-1.5314 0.505,-0.0242 0.143,-0.55815 -0.769,-0.1209 0.174,-1.53039 0.535,-0.14911 -0.256,-0.65689 0.785,-0.26396 -0.791,-0.29923 0.378,-1.79838 0.559,-0.44229 -0.669,-0.43121 0.413,-0.53196 -0.431,-0.16825 0.372,-1.40042 0.576,-0.23172 -0.5,-0.35867 0.518,0 0.343,-0.59241 -0.262,-0.89869 1.21,-0.65286 -0.25,-0.74756 0.989,-0.1743 0.506,0.35867 -0.023,-0.97626 0.467,0.67099 0.404,-0.67804 z m -0.285,-2.21549 0.251,1.06089 -1.069,-0.6055 0.818,-0.45539 z m 13.096,-26.52437 -0.617,1.4518 0.021,-0.82615 0.596,-0.62565 z'
                      onClick={() => alert("Andaman and Nicobar Islands")}
                    />
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: You can try `title="Andama"` instead of using `xlink:title`. It achieves same result

Comment: Thanks @kunquan I tried that in react and nothing seems to workout.

Comment: create a title child element of the <a> or the <path> and have the title be the text content of the title element.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson for commenting. However, could you please show how can I do that.

Comment: Which part of my explanation don't you understand?

Comment: Try <a xlinkTitle='Andaman Nicobar' />

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRovinsky it worked.